# Node.js, нужна ли аутентификация внутри локального хоста?

Tags: node.js, клиент-сервер, аутентификация

*Имею такую связку:*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При подключении клиента к серверу, происходит проверка неких данных, нужных для аутентификации, и если всё хорошо, то тогда сервер отправляет токен на основе секретного ключа.

Вопрос в том, *нужно ли проводить аутентификацию того самого стороннего приложения, если оно может лишь отправлять запросы на сервер в одностороннем порядке, учитывая его доступность только из локального хоста,* или это вообще лишнее? По сути серверу нужно лишь знать, то ли приложение к нему подключилось, но вот стоит ли выдавать ему токен, или достаточно лишь самого факта, что запрос на сервер пришёл от локального хоста?

Comment: я бы сделал аутентификацию если Приложение ведёт себя так же как Клиент и имеет доступ к тому же api. если нет - отдельный endpoint без аутентификации.

Comment: @nörbörnën всё верно, приложение скорее функции клиента выполняет. Тогда так и поступлю, спасибо. :)